# Order by date on category dynamically - Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a page and I'm currently printing out the product categories with the shortcode `[product_categories limit="5"]`. Currently, I get the first 5 alphabetically. I want to order by date ASC.

I've tried `orderby="date"` but it doesn't work. Is there a simply way to fix this, or do I have to make some filter functions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Woocommerce is off-topic  You have even included a tag which specifically states this.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using the `[product_categories]` shortcode, you query for taxonomy / terms, and not posts.  Other than posts, terms can not be ordered using `date`, as terms did not save the date they were added or modified.

When you are querying for terms you can use the following `orderby` parameters:

- name - Default
- count
- slug
- term_group
- term_order
- term_id
- none

Take a look at [WP_Term_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/) parameters in the codex.
So no, you cannot order terms by date.

Also I cannot tell you if the WC shortcode supports all these orderby parameters from the get go.